# Change the next thumbnail to text

Tags: attachments

Hey i am using this theme called starblog and on  the single gallery page it shows this cpde below

```
<div id="nav-images" class="navigation clearfix">
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_image_link() ?></div>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_image_link() ?></div>
        </div>
```

It shows the thumbnails of the next and previous image but instead i want it show text "Next Image" "Previous Image" how do i change this

Comment: `next_image_link()` accepts a second parameter `text`,

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress function [`next_image_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_image_link) do accept a second parameter `$text` which will show up  instead of a thumbnail image.

**Example -**

```
<?php next_image_link( false, 'Next Image' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Just replace your code above with this.

```
<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link('&#8734;','Next Image','Previous Image'); ?></p></div>
```

Read more about customizing these links [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links)

Comment: Yes but i think the way you just did it it won't be linked

Comment: Sorry wasn't thinking..check the edit

Comment: make sure to check the answer correct if this works for you.